# CMake: how to link libraries from a parallel dir

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to organize libs and targets in separate (parallel) dirs. This seems to be a natural way to organize files to me, but I am really new and not sure. I was able to replicate the on-line CMake tutorials but it includes libs in a sub directory rather than a parallel one.

In the coding below, I try to define variables for the lib sources /headers with parent scope, then try to add a library in the root directory and make a custom target depend on it. I then link the lib to the target in sub dir. Obviously I missed something and I can't figure it out.

Below is my directory structure:

- root/
- root/lib/test.cpp, test.h
- root/app1/app.cpp, app.h

In the root/CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_library (lib_test STATIC 
    ${lib_test_sources}
    ${lib_test_headers}
    )
add_custom_target(test DEPENDS lib_test)
```

In the root/lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(lib_test_sources
    ${lib_test_sources}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.cpp
    PARENT_SCOPE
    )

set(lib_test_headers
   ${lib_test_headers}
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.h
   PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

In the root/app1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(test_app app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_app lib_test)
```

Comment: `then try to add a library in the root directory.` - Usually the library is added in its subdirectory, but your approach is correct too (assuming you have `add_subdirectory(app1)` at the end of your `root/CMakeLists.txt` script). **What is a problem**? Do you get an error message, or what? Note, that for *dependency between targets* `add_dependencies` command should be used, *DEPENDS* option is for dependency between *target* and file.

Comment: The problem likely is that the `${lib_test_sources}` and `${lib_test_headers}` variables are empty in the parent CMakeLists, as they are not propagated to the parent (no matter where the `add_subdirectory` is).

Comment: @axalis: These `set` commands have *PARENT_SCOPE* option, which forces propagation to the parent.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Then it should work in general, maybe just the `include_directories("lib")` is missing, or something else got wrong.

Comment: @Tsyvarev When you talked about the dependencies I realized that I forgot to link Qt libraries to my libraries! Both my executable and libraries use Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the library definition is put in the subdir as well as the source definitions, i.e. move the

```
add_library (lib_test STATIC 
    ${lib_test_sources}
    ${lib_test_headers}
    )
```

into the `root/lib/CMakeLists.txt`. Then you would not need the `PARENT_SCOPE` and it should work as well.

Note that you might also need to add

```
include_directories("lib")
```

in case the `app.cpp` includes `test.h`, to find the headers located in the subdir.

Comment: I actually prefer to add library in the sub dir. Thanks!